# Create sequence starting with maximum id from a table

Tags: postgresql, sequence

I'm trying to create a sequence in the following way:

```
create sequence some_seq start with (select max(id) + 1 from some_table);
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
```

I've also tried this approach:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    min_seq_value int8 := (select max(id) + 1 from some_table);
BEGIN
    create sequence some_seq start with min_seq_value;
END; $$;
```

But it gives me:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "min_seq_value"
```

It seems to be pretty basic but I can't get it working. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL for this.

Comment: @McNets I need to make it with database migration I mean I can't use terminal. Is there a way to use the `\set` command and etc in a .sql file?

Comment: @Colin'tHart thank you very much, didn't know about it (I'm a developer). works!

Comment: @McNets ok, sorry, missed that, seems to be the same stuff I was able to solve the issue with. thank you!

Comment: @Colin'tHart: no need for dynamic SQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the sequence, then set the value afterwards:

```
create sequence some_seq;
select setval('some_seq', (select max(id) from some_table));
```

You probably also want to "link" the sequence to the table's column as well:

```
alter sequence some_seq
  owned by some_table.id;
```

---

For modern Postgres version (>= 10), it is recommended to use an `identity` column instead:

```
alter table some_table
   alter id add generated always as identity;

select setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('some_table', 'id'), (select max(id) from some_table));
```

Comment: thanks for the solution! but I didn't want to link the sequence to the table so dynamic SQL fits my problem perfectly

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich: then just leave out the `alter sequence ... owned by`